# What design pattern does bootstrap.js plugins use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a new to JS and jQuery in general and have been exploring the [bootrap js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js) repository quite actively.  There are a few things that have come to my notice about the plugins in bootstrap.

The plugins follow the following structure/skeleton :

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Dropdown = function (element) {

  }

  Dropdown.VERSION = '3.3.4'

  Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function (e) {


  }

  Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function (e) {

  }




  // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown             = Plugin
  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


  // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
  // ===================================



}(jQuery);
```

(example taken from [dropdown.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js))

When the plugin user passes the value to the plugin eg.,

```
$('#mynav').dropdown('hidden'); // just an example
```

the value is use in the following fashion internally inside the plugin :

```
data[option].call($this) // just an example
```

There are a few more things that I have noticed about the bootstrap plugins in the way they typically function but my question is, what design pattern does the bootstrap plugins use(if any)?  I would be really interested in knowing that design pattern is.

Comment: Don't think this is a particular *design pattern*. Seems more of a coding convention / style the devs have chosen.

Comment: @Phil, in it's basic form, it looks a lot like a constructor pattern to me.